# Excel 'Cancel' button breaks entire application

Tags: vba

Having trouble with calling an endpoint (connectionStringURI = http:\company.com:8000/Prices?format=csv&Transaction.ID=5456, e.g.).  Call it with this code:

```
Set curveSource = curveDestination.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & connectionStringURI, Destination:=DestinationSheet.Range("A1:F3000"))
curveSource.Name = "Prices"
curveSource.TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
curveSource.TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
curveSource.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
curveSource.SaveData = True
```

The call to the URI returns a csv file.  Everything works great.  When this code is hit:

```
curveSource.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

I see an Excel dialogue box that says, "Contacting the server for information", and it has a 'Cancel' button on it.  If the user does nothing, it displays the data properly in the DestinationSheet.  If the user clicks the 'Cancel' button while this is occurring, it breaks the entire spreadsheet.  From then on, it throws an error at

```
curveSource.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

The error is, "Run-time error: '1004'.  Excel cannot find the text file to refresh this external data range".  The user has to close the file the Excel file and reopen it to get it to work.  Can't find anything about this error after hours of googling.

I've tried setting everything to Nothing, removing QueryTables, very frustrating. Nothing seems to fix the issue.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this would help but you can try `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` before that line, and revert back to True afterwards maybe. And/or `On Error Resume Next` before the line that give the error and `On Error Goto 0` afterwards.

Comment: Thanks.  The users have said that they click 'Cancel' because they realized the Transaction ID was incorrect.  So, I have to get the code to work again after they click 'Cancel'.  It may be that the query is still executing under the hood, even though 'Cancel' was clicked.  And that's preventing me from sending a new request.  We'll see what waiting a while does.